# wall collision detection with html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am making a game and there is a wall that I don't want the player to pass. I am using html5 canvas and have a player object to hold the x and y values. The wall is at x: 650 and y: 0. Since the player is 20x20 pixels when its x coordinate is 630, it touches the wall.

```
if(player.x > 630 && player.y <= 500) {
    player.x = 630;
}
```

What is wrong with this code? I appreciate any help!

Comment: What kind of blur? In which broswer? What kind of code are you using for drawing your player? What kind of code are you using for drawing your walls? Can you reproduce the behavior inside a jsfiddle? You need to answer those questions if you want some help.

Comment: What is the expected behavior ? What is the faulty one ?

Comment: Per your edit, it looks like you've found your own solution -- set x=630 when it exceeds 630? If you have found your solution you might delete your question because it's so specific that it's unlikely to help future viewers. ;-)

Comment: @markE, but it got an [almost canonical answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33866205/3702797) now...

Comment: Is the wall a one pixel block ? Thats what 650,0 is eh?

Comment: @Kaiido, Blindman67 has a good answer to an unacceptable question -- ouch! The good news is that good collision questions are asked all the time and he can (should!) post a similar answer to one of those good questions. I guess the (almost unacceptable) alternative is to completely alter the question to match the answer -- again ouch!

Answer (score 4):

**Answer**

The code you have give is OK, there is nothing wrong with it. So I suspect the problem is elsewhere in the code, most likely in the movement code. If you are moving the player after the wall test and then display it, the player may start to creep into the wall, but without the rest of the code it is hard to know what is wrong with your code.

I have included more details on the correct way to do collision tests as there are two answers showing only a partial solution. It is there as a general guide to collision testing and may not be directly applicable to the question.

**Inter frame movement**

The correct way to reflect an object from a surface.

You must take into account that the ball is moving between frames and that the collision may have happened at any time during the previous frame. The ball's distance from the wall after the collision is dependent on when during the previous frame it hit the wall. This is important if the ball moves slowly or quickly.

```
var dx = 10; // delta x velocity of object in pixels
var wx = 10; // width of object in pixels
var px = 90;  // position of object in pixels
var wallX = 105; // position of wall


px += dx;  // move the ball. Its position is now  100.
           // its right side is at px + wx = 110.
// test if it has it the wall
if(px+wx > wallX){
    dx = -dx; // reflect delta x
    // The object is 5 pixel into the wall.
    // The object has hit the wall some time during the last frame
    // We need to adjust the position as the ball may have been
    // traveling away from the wall for some time during the last frame.
    var dist = (px+wx)-wallX; // get the distance into the wall
    px -= dist*2; // the object hit the wall at position 95 and has been 
                  // traveling away since then so it is easy to just 
                  // subtract 2 times the distance the ball entered the wall
    // the above two lines can be done in one
    // px -= ((px+wx)-wallX)*2;
}
```

**Why it matters**

Below is a simulation of a ball bouncing inside the canvas.

To illustrate that the ball is moving between frames it has been motion blurred to show its motion between frames. Please note this is not the perfect solution as the bounce is assumed to occur while the ball is in linear motion while infact it is in freefall and under constant acceleration. But it still conserves energy.

In the correct test the height the ball bounces back to, stays around the same over time. No energy is lost or gained.

Right click to turn off the inter frame adjustment and you will notice that the ball begins to decrease its height each frame. This is because at each collision the ball loses a little energy because it motion during the previous frame is not taken into account when positioning it after the collision test. It will settle down to a constant rate when the collision occurres at precisely the frame time. When that will be is very hard to determine in advance.

Left click to slow the simulation frame rate, left click again to return to normal.

The code below is not really part of the answer, it is there to demonstrate the effect of not correctly adjusting the position during collision test on the overall accuracy of the simulation.

```js
// helper functions. NOT part of the answer
var canvas = document.getElementById("canV"); 
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var mouseButton = 0;
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown',function(event){mouseButton = event.which;});
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup'  ,function(){mouseButton = 0;});
canvas.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(e){ e.preventDefault();}, false);
var currentSurface = ctx;
var createImage = function (w, h) {// create an canvas image of size w,h and attach context 2d
    var image = document.createElement("canvas");  
    image.width = w;
    image.height = h !== undefined?h:w; 
    currentSurface = image.ctx = image.getContext("2d"); 
    return image;
}  
var setColour = function (fillC, strokeC, lineW) { 
    currentSurface.fillStyle = fillC !== undefined ? fillC : currentSurface.fillStyle;
    currentSurface.strokeStyle = strokeC !== undefined ? strokeC : currentSurface.strokeStyle;
    currentSurface.lineWidth = lineW !== undefined ? lineW : currentSurface.lineWidth;
}
var circle = function(x,y,r,how){
    currentSurface.beginPath();
    currentSurface.arc(x,y,r,0,Math.PI*2);
    how = how.toLowerCase().replace(/[os]/g,"l"); // how to draw
    switch(how){
        case "f":  // fill
            currentSurface.fill();
            break;
        case "l":
            currentSurface.stroke();
            break;
        case "lf":
            currentSurface.stroke();
            currentSurface.fill();
            break;
        case "fl":
            currentSurface.fill();
            currentSurface.stroke();
            break;
    }
}
function createGradImage(size,col1,col2){
    var image = createImage(size);
    var g = currentSurface.createLinearGradient(0,0,0,currentSurface.canvas.height);
    g.addColorStop(0,col1);
    g.addColorStop(1,col2);
    currentSurface.fillStyle = g;
    currentSurface.fillRect(0,0,currentSurface.canvas.width,currentSurface.canvas.height);    
    return image;
}
function createColouredBall (ballR,col) {
    var ball = createImage(ballR*2);
    var unit = ballR/100;
    setColour("black");
    circle(ballR,ballR,ballR,"f");
    setColour("hsl("+col+",100%,30%)");
    circle(ballR-unit*3,ballR-unit*3,ballR-unit*7,"f");
    setColour("hsl("+col+",100%,50%)");
    circle(ballR-unit*10,ballR-unit*10,ballR-unit*16,"f");
    setColour("White");
    circle(ballR-unit*50,ballR-unit*50,unit*16,"f");
    
    return ball;
}
//===================================    
//    _                          
//   /_\  _ _  ____ __ _____ _ _ 
//  / _ \| ' \(_-< V  V / -_) '_|
// /_/ \_\_||_/__/\_/\_/\___|_|  
//                              
// ==================================
// Answer code

// lazy coder variables
var w = canvas.width;
var h = canvas.height;

// ball is simulated 5cm 
var pixSize = 0.24; // in millimeters for simulation

// Gravity is 9.8 ms^2 so convert to pixels per frame squared
// Assuming constant 60 frames per second. ()
var gravity = 9800*pixSize/60; 
gravity *= 0.101; // because Earth's gravity is stupidly large let's move to Pluto

// ball 5cm 
var ballR = (25/pixSize)/2;          // radius is 2.5cm for 5cm diamiter ball
var ballX = w/2;                     // get center of canvas
var ballY = ballR+3;                 // start at the top
var ballDX = (Math.random()-0.5)*15; // start with random x speed
ballDX += ballDX < 0 ? -5 : 5;       // make sure it's not too slow
var ballDY = 0;                      // star with no downward speed;
var ballLastX = ballX;
var ballLastY = ballY;

//create an image of the Ball
var ball = createColouredBall(ballR,Math.floor(Math.random()*360)); // create an image of ball

// create a background. Image is small as it does not have much detail in it
var background = createGradImage(16,"#5af","#08C");
// time to run for
var runFor = 10*60; // ten secons yimes 60 frames per second

// draws the ball motion blured. This introduces extra complexity
var drawMotionBlur = function(image,px,py,dx,dy,steps){
    var i,sx,sy;
    sx = dx / steps;
    sy = dy / steps;
    px -= dx; // move back to start position
    py -= dy; 
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1/(steps*0.8); // set alpha to slightly higher for each step
    for(i = 0; i < steps; i+= 1){
        ctx.drawImage(image,px+i*sx,py+i*sy);
    }
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1; // reset alpha
    
}
// style for text
ctx.fillStyle = "white";
ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.lineJoin = "round"; // stop some letters getting ears.
ctx.lineWidth = 3;
ctx.textBaseline = "bottom";
var textCenterX = w/2;
var maxHeight = Infinity;
var lastMaxHeight = ballY;
var slowMotion = false;  // slow motion flag
var frameTravel = true;  // use frame travel in collision test 
var update = function(){
    var blurSteps = 10;  // motion blur ball render steps
    const bSteps = 10;
    if(mouseButton === 1){
        slowMotion = ! slowMotion;
        mouseButton = 0;
    }
    if(mouseButton === 3){
        frameTravel = ! frameTravel;
        ballX = w/2;                     // get center of canvas
        ballY = ballR+3;                 // start at the top
        ballDY = 0;                      // start at 0 y speed
        mouseButton = 0;
    }
    // clear the canvas with background canvas image
    ctx.drawImage(background,0,0,w,h);
    
    ballDY += gravity; // accelrate due to grav
    // add deltas to ball position
    ballX += ballDX; 
    ballY += ballDY;
    // test for collison on left and right walls. Need to 
    // ajust for motion blur
    if (ballX < ballR) {
        ballDX = -ballDX; // refect delta x
        if (frameTravel) { // if using frame travel time
            // blur the outward traveling ball only for the time it has been traveling away
            blurSteps = Math.ceil(10 * ((ballX - ballR) / -ballDX));
            // get position it should have traveled since
            ballX -= (ballX - ballR) * 2;
        }else{
            ballX = ballR; // move ball to touching wall
            blurSteps = 1; // there is no outward motion
        }
    } else
    if (ballX > w - ballR) {
        ballDX = -ballDX;
        if (frameTravel) { // if using frame travel time
            // blur the outward traveling ball only for the time it has been traveling away
            blurSteps = Math.ceil(10 * ((ballX - (w - ballR)) / -ballDX));
            ballX -= (ballX - (w - ballR)) * 2;
        }else{
            ballX = w - ballR; // move ball to touching wall
            blurSteps = 1; // there is no outward motion
        }
    }
    if (ballY > h - ballR) {
        ballDY = -ballDY;
        // to show max height
        lastMaxHeight = maxHeight;
        maxHeight = Infinity;
        if (frameTravel) { // if using frame travel time
            // blur the outward traveling ball only for the time it has been traveling away
            blurSteps = Math.ceil(10 * ((ballY - (h - ballR)) / -ballDY));
            ballY -= (ballY - (h - ballR)) * 2;
        }else{
            ballY = h - ballR; // move ball to touching wall
            blurSteps = 1; // there is no outward motion
        }
    }        
    // draw the ball motion blured
    drawMotionBlur(
        ball,                    // image to draw
        ballX - ballR,             // offset radius
        ballY - ballR,
        ballDX * (blurSteps / bSteps),  // speed and adjust for bounced
        ballDY * (blurSteps / bSteps),
        blurSteps                // number of blurs
    );
    // show max height. Yes it is min but everything is upside down.
    maxHeight = Math.min(maxHeight,ballY);
    lastMaxHeight = Math.min(ballY,lastMaxHeight);

    // show max height
    ctx.font = "12px arial black";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0,lastMaxHeight - ballR);
    ctx.lineTo(w,lastMaxHeight - ballR);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fillText("Max height.",40,lastMaxHeight - ballR + 6);


    var str = ""; // display status string
    if(slowMotion){   // show left click help
        str += "10fps."
        ctx.fillText("click for 60fps.",textCenterX,43);
    }else{
        str += "60fps."
        ctx.fillText("click for 10fps.",textCenterX,43);
    }

    if(frameTravel){ // show mode and right click help
        str += " Mid frame collision.";
        ctx.fillText("Right click for Simple collision",textCenterX,55);
    }else{
        str += " Simple collision.";
        ctx.fillText("Right click for mid frame collision",textCenterX,55);
    }
    // display help text
    ctx.font = "18px arial black";  
    ctx.strokeText(str,textCenterX,30);
    ctx.fillText(str,textCenterX,28);

    if(slowMotion){
        setTimeout(update,100); // show in slow motion
    }else{
        requestAnimationFrame(update); // request next frame (1/60) seconds from now
    }

    // all done
}
update(); // to start the ball rolling
```

```css
.canC { width:500px;  height:500px;}
```

```html
<canvas class="canC" id="canV" width=500 height=500></canvas>
```

Comment: This is quite an in-depth answer to collision detection, however the op did state a simple question, not how to implement frame perfect collision detection :)

Comment: Funny to read, complete and correct solution, you've got my upvote :-) @Canvas, OP asked "what is wrong with my code ?", everything that makes it imperfect can be though as "wrong" no? (+ I think this will be more useful for future readers than just a typo correction)

Comment: Oh dear, I guess I read the answers already given and lost sight of the question. Silly me. Will reword it a little to help the OP and fix typos (english is not my first language)

Comment: @Blindman67. Please consider posting your useful answer to one of the future collision questions that will inevitably be asked. Upvote. :-)  Appending: I just searched SO and there are 551 previous questions on [canvas] + collision. Perhaps one of those can be a suitable host to your good answer...

Answer (score 0):

For a wall running along the X axis at the bottom (Y = 0) of a 650 x 650 field, we would want:

```
if (player.y <= 20) {
    player.y = 20;
}
```

For a wall running along the Y axis at the left side (X = 0) of a 650 x 650 field, we would want:

```
if (player.x <= 20) {
    player.x = 20;
}
```

For a wall running along the Y axis at the right side (X = 650) of a 650 x 650 field, we would want:

```
if (player.x >= 630) {
    player.x = 630;
}
```

For a wall running along the X axis at the top (Y = 650) of a 650 x 650 field, we would want:

```
if (player.y >= 630) {
    player.y = 630;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is similar to the code I use, if we attach horizontal (h) and vertical (v) velocity attributes to the player object we can multiply them by negative one to get them to bounce off of the wall if the player is going to go beyond the bounds. Or if you want it to stop, set them equal to zero at the wall.

```
//player.x+player.h gives us the future position of the player
if (player.x+player.h>630||player.x+player.h<0)
{
    player.h*=-1;//bounce
    //stop player.h=0;
}
if (player.y+player.v>500||player.y+player.v<0)
{
   player.v*=-1;
   //stop player.v=0;
}
//new player coordinates
player.x+=player.h;
player.y+=player.v;
```

Hope this helps.